# How to split picture 240x240 to 6400 box's

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have pictureBox 240x240
I must split this picture into 6400 boxe's 3x3.
I don't know how this calculated.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        int pointX = e.X;
        int pointY = e.Y;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with the 3x3 boxes?

Comment: I have data from 80x80 bitmap. I must add value to 240x240 bitmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Box number = 80 * ((pointy - 1) / 3) + (pointx - 1) / 3 + 1